# How to I get this <SPAN> element to span 100% of LI?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm working on this navigation bar, and I'm almost done, but I just have pretty much one issue that needs to be solved. My navigation uses jQuery and the code targets `<SPAN>` elements to open the submenus. My issue is that for some reason the span doesn't include the whole `LI` area. There's a whole bunch of "empty" space that you can click on and nothing happens at all. How do I get the `span` to cover the whole `LI` area? I've tried messing with width's, padding and margins and none of it works.

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m65b10ph/).

**CSS**

```
#navbar {
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0%; 
        background-color: #29568F;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #29568F;
    }

    #menu-icon {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
    }

    #menu-icon img {
        height: 16px;
        width: 21px;
        align: center;
        margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
        position: relative;
        top: 2px;
    }

    #empty-tab{

    }

    .nav-tabs {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #29568F;
        margin: 0px 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        list-style-type: none;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
        font: 18px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
    }

    .nav-tabs li {
        float: left;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        text-align: center;
        border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
    }

    .nav-tabs li span {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .nav-tabs li:last-child {
        border: 0px;
    }

    .nav-tabs li:hover,
    .nav-tabs > .open {
        background-color: #3399CC;
    }

    #active {
        background-color: #3399CC;
    }

    .nav-tabs li a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
        font: 18px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav-tabs">
        <li id="menu-icon"><span><img src="/images/menu-icon.png">Menu</span></li>
        <li><span>Dogs <div class="arrow-closed"></div></span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><span>Meet the Breeds<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span>
                    <ul class="drop-menu">
                        <li><span>Sort A - Z <div class="arrow-closed"></div></span>
                            <ul class="slide-menu">
                                <li>Breeds A - F</li>
                                <li>Breeds G - L</li>
                                <li>Breeds M - R</li>
                                <li>Breeds S - Z</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><span>Sort by AKC Group <div class="arrow-closed"></div></span>
                            <ul class="slide-menu">
                                <li>Sporting Group</li>
                                <li>Working Group</li>
                                <li>Herding Group</li>
                                <li>Hound Group</li>
                                <li>Terrier Group</li>
                                <li>Non-Sporting Group</li>
                                <li>Toy Group</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><span>Sort by Size <div class="arrow-closed"></div></span>
                            <ul class="slide-menu">
                                <li>X-Small (&le 10in)</li>
                                <li>Small (10in &gt &lt 15in)</li>
                                <li>Medium (15in &ge &lt 21in)</li>
                                <li>Large (21in &ge &lt 28in)</li>
                                <li>X-Large (28in +)</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><span>Sort by Coat <div class="arrow-closed"></div></span>
                            <ul class="slide-menu">
                                <li>Very Short/Hairless</li>
                                <li>Short Coat</li>
                                <li>Medium Coats</li>
                                <li>Long Coats</li>
                                <li>Non-Shedding Coats</li>
                                <li>Curly Coats</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><span>Sort by Trait <div class="arrow-closed"></div></span>
                            <ul class="slide-menu">
                                <li>Apartment Suitable</li>
                                <li>Laid Back</li>
                                <li>Athletic</li>
                                <li>Protective</li>
                                <li>Extroverted</li>
                                <li>Pet Friendly</li>
                                <li>Cuddle-Buddies</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span>Supplies<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span>
                    <ul class="drop-menu">
                        <li><span>Crates & Kennels</span></li>
                        <li><span>Bowls & Dishes</span></li>
                        <li><span>Collars & Leashes</span></li>
                        <li><span>Toys & Games</span></li>
                        <li><span>Grooming</span></li>
                        <li><span>Apparal & Accessories</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span>Finding a Dog<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li><span>Cats<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><span>Cat Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Cat Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Cat Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Cat Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Cat Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Cat Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Birds<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><span>Bird Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Bird Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Bird Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Bird Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Bird Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Bird Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Small Mammals<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><span>Sm.Mammal Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Sm.Mammal Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Sm.Mammal Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Sm.Mammal Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Sm.Mammal Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Sm.Mammal Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Articles<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><span>Article Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Article Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Article Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Article Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Article Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Article Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Videos<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><span>Video Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Video Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Video Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Video Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Video Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>Video Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Updates<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><span>More Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>More Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>More Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>More Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>More Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
                <li><span>More Links<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've outlined the span in red. This is only for visualization purposes so I (we) can see where the span is. When the span actually covers the whole area, it will be removed. I've also hidden the CSS for the arrows, because it was causing the menu to act funky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple:

```
.nav-tabs li {
    float: left;
    /* padding: 10px 20px; */ /* remove */
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.nav-tabs li span {
    display:block; /* add */
    padding: 10px 20px; /* add */
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

You need to remove the padding on the `li` as it won't allow the child `span` to expand in the `li` entirely. Instead apply the padding to the `span` and add `display:block;` as a `span` is an inline element by default and will only expand enough to encompass its content.

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/m65b10ph/1/

Also for the 4th level menu to be positioned correctly, you need a `clear` fix because of the floated span in it. That's because the containing `li` has a calculated height of 0:

```
.drop-menu li:after {
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/mh7waw46/1/

Comment: I was implementing what you suggested, and I want to tag this being answered, but suddenly my 4th level menu is acting up. The 4th level menu is supposed to be absolute positioned to the LI parent. But now for some reason it's positioning itself relative to the UL grandparent. Nothing else in the code has changed, and I can't get it to line back up with the parent LI. Here's the new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mh7waw46/ can you spot where I'm going wrong?

Comment: That's because the containing li has a calculated height of 0, you need to clear the floated span in it. See the updated answer.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad to be of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

`<span>` is an `display: inline;` element, which in default takes only the area of the content. `display: block;` element takes 100% of the available width. you can set the `<span>` to `display: block;` or use `<div>` instead, but in this way you also need to set the padding of the `<li>` element to 0 so the inner element (`<span>`) will get the full width of the `<li>` element. you can then set padding to the `<span>`.